# jQuery click interrupt animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I've been creating a slideshow for a site that automatically scrolls through several products.
I need this to both scroll through automatically and when a button is clicked move to the next product.

Initially I created this to work via click event, then automatically as below but can't seem to get it to do both.

I'm new to jQuery so any help is much appreciated, I imagine I may need to rewrite this to get it to do what I need.

I thought perhaps I could call the same functions in a click event, but that seems to create another instance of the product, and animates that.

Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
homeslide_1();
});

function homeslide_1() {
$('.homeproducticon').delay(5000).animate({ 
//animates an icon fro, 259px to 1px to emulate page turn
width: '1px',
height: '153px'
}, 1000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
  $('.homeproducticon').fadeOut().hide(); //fade out the icon
  $('.product1').fadeOut().hide(); //fade out and hide the container for product1
  $('.product2').fadeIn().css('display', 'inline-block'); //fade in and display the 2nd container 
  $('.homeheader').css('background-image', 'url(img/homeheaderbackgrd2.png)'); //changes background image
  $('.homeproducticon2').css({ //displays the 2nd product icon
    'display': 'inline-block',
    'width': '1px',
    'height': '153px'
  }).animate({ //animates the page turn effect 
  width: '259px',
  height: '153px'
  }, 1000);
    homeslide_2(); //moves on to the next slide
});
};

function homeslide_2() {
$('.homeproducticon2').delay(5000).animate({ 
      width: '1px',
      height: '153px'
      }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        $('.homeproducticon2').fadeOut().hide(); 
        $('.product2').fadeOut().hide();
        $('.product3').fadeIn().css('display', 'inline-block');
        $('.homeheader').css('background-image', 'url(img/homeheaderbackgrd3.png)');
        $('.homeproducticon3').css({
          'display': 'inline-block',
          "width": "1px",
          "height": "153px"
        }).animate({ 
        width: '259px',
        height: '153px'
        }, 1000);
    homeslide_3();
});
};


function homeslide_3() {
$('.homeproducticon3').delay(5000).animate({ 
                width: '1px',
                height: '153px'
                }, 1000, function() {
                  // Animation complete.
                  $('.homeproducticon3').fadeOut().hide(); 
                  $('.product3').fadeOut().hide();
                  $('.product1').fadeIn().css('display', 'inline-block');
                  $('.homeheader').css('background-image', 'url(img/homeheaderbackgrd.png)');
                  $('.homeproducticon').css({
                    'display': 'inline-block',
                    "width": "1px",
                    "height": "153px"
                  }).animate({ 
                  width: '259px',
                  height: '153px'
                  }, 1000);
    homeslide_1();
});
};
```

Thanks for any help!
Jonathan

edit: as per Zeaklous's question:

I was pretty sure it wasn't working which is why I didn't include it, but this was my attempt to combine the two:

```
//home product changer1
//home-arrow1 click
$(document).ready(function(){
     "use strict";
    $('.home-arrow1').click(function(){ 
    homeslide_1();
   });
});

//home product changer2
//home-arrow1 click
$(document).ready(function(){
     "use strict";
    $('.home-arrow2').click(function(){ 
    homeslide_2();
   });
});
//home product changer3
//home-arrow1 click
$(document).ready(function(){
     "use strict";
    $('.home-arrow3').click(function(){ 
    homeslide_3();
   });
});
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at the click event implementation?

Comment: And I would use one function for all of them, just changing the elements that they effect (either by class -> going to next one in class or by putting them in an array -> next element in the array). Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: Thanks for the added code, you're doing what you thought you were doing - creating a new instance of the function. You need to structure the function to run on a setInterval or something similar. That would also allow the click-to-change functionality a lot easier to implement as well. If you provide a jsfiddle or a live example we can edit I'll be glad to help you with the implementation

Comment: Thanks.
I'm trying to put one together but this has become a large site it's a bit of a mess cutting out things unneeded. 
I'll post it when it's done :) 
Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a plugin? They're there because their well-tested in different browsers and we don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Plugins are for the weak

Comment: Partly as I got this far with it and thought it would be good to learn. I thought it would require a lot of messing about with other peoples code. Can you recommend a plugin that does what I'm looking for? As it's not just an image slideshow.

Comment: There are lots, haha http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/12/best-jquery-page-flip-book-effect-with-examples/

Comment: Work smarter not harder. If you have the time to learn I suggest doing it the hard way, but some of us have code to ship yesterday.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle, it's far from perfect.
A lot of the CSS isn't needed for that but it'll give you an idea.

For some reason the image is loading in at the start at the wrong size, after the first transition everything is correct.

The image on the far right is the arrow to click to the next frame/product

http://jsfiddle.net/snoopyj/eHQZr/

Comment: You also only need a single document.ready.

Comment: I did wonder about that Christopher and was looking it up here earlier :) Under what conditions would you need more than one then?

Comment: I agree with the what your saying Christopher too, as this project does need to be done soon, I just made such progress with this up to this point I wanted to complete it rather than start again :)

Comment: Thanks for the link Zeaklous, the page turn I need is even simpler than that :) It's more how to rewrite to make it work automatically and on click.

Comment: You only have one document, so you would always only use one. :}

Comment: Haha, when you put it like that Christopher -_-.

Thanks Zeaklous, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for any suggestions you made.

My current solution was to use and customise http://ekallevig.com/jshowoff/ as it had a slide animation and allowed html to be used in the slides (not just images like some)

As it happens the client changed what they were after a little animation wise so a lot of what I originally required in my question changed.

If I come back to my code and find a full solution I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close to doing what you want to do. I think to complete your work you need to add an additional layer of complexity to your click event handling: You will need to counter the automatic animation. This will probably require the jquery .stop() method http://api.jquery.com/stop/ this will also be helpful in preventing unwanted animation overlap if the user clicks multiple times.

For a useful article discussing the use of the stop method with animations, check this out: http://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/

Sorry this isn't a comprehensive answer, but hopefully it helps.